# Let P be Sylow p-subgroup of G and let M be any subgroup of G which contains N_G(P). Prove that |G:M|=1 mod p.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Could anyone help me out please? This is from Dummit and Foote Exercise 4.5.51. It looks like a very interesting result.

My idea is that $|G:M||M:N_G(P)|=|G:N_G(P)|=n_p\equiv1$ ($\mathrm{mod}$ $p$). But I couldn't find a way to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I imagine you've read Section 4.5, and everything up to it?  I'm glad you find the result interesting, but you've failed to include any references to topics you've recently read about, how they might apply, and your failed to include any thoughts or work indicating how you might want to proceed.  This is not a homework completion service.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for your comment. This is my first time posting a question. So sorry about not mentioning any thoughts. I was thinking that n_p=|G:N_G(P)|=1 mod p and then |G:M||M:N_G(P)|=1 mod p. However, I couldn't find a way to proceed from here. Could you give me some hints? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Consider Sylow Theory in $M$, look at $n_p(M)$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you very much. I think I got it. Since |M:N_M(P)|=1 mod p and N_M(P)=N_G(P), |M:N_G(P)|=1 mod p. So |G:M|=1 mod p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Sylow's third theorem, $|M:N_M(P)|=1\mod p$. Since $N_G(P)\leq M$, $N_M(P)=N_G(P)\cap M=N_G(P)$. So $|M:N_G(P)|=1\mod p$. Hence $|G:M|=1\mod p$.

Comment: Yes! This is it! Next time add your efforts to the post. Then people will not vote to close. +1 from me!

Comment: @NickyHekster OK. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the set of cosets $\{gM:g \in G\}$, and let $P$ act on $X$ by left multiplication. Then $X$ is partitioned into $P$-orbits, and by the orbit-stabilizer theorem the length of any orbit is a divisor of $|P|$, hence is either a proper power of $p$ or $1$. It is easily to see that $[M]$ is a single-element orbit, because $PM=M$. It suffices to prove $[M]$ is the only one, since then any other orbit has length divided by $p$, and the total number of elements in $X$ is the foem $pm+1$.

Suppose $gM \in X$ forms another orbit of a single element. Let $a\in P$, by definition $PgM=gM$, and thus $g^{-1}Pg \in M$, which is another Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$. By the second Sylow theorem, there exists $m \in M$ such that $g^{-1}Pg = m^{-1}Pm$. Henceforth $gm^{-1} \in N_G(P)$, and it follows trivially that $gm^{-1} \in M$. So $g \in M$, $gM = M$, $[M]$ is the only single orbit under the action of $P$.